# Excel chart into Word - losing underlines

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, paste

I am trying to copy an Excel chart into Word as a picture but I am losing the underlines under certain cells. I am copying as a picture (alt+H, C, P, P, Enter), and pasting into word as a picture (Alt+V, S, Enter). Again, I am losing some of the underlines in certain cells and I can't figure out why.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Some screen shots would help us understand your question. Upload any image(s) to [Imgur](http://www.imgur.com) and you will get link(s) you can share. [Edit] your question to include the link(s) and someone with sufficient reputation will inline the image(s) for you.

Answer (score 0):

Universal way to copy any image:

1. Press <kbd>PrtSc</kbd> button on keyboard to get screenshot
2. Open `Paintbrush`, or any other image redactor
3. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> buttons combination on keyboard to insert screenshot
4. Crop your image if you need